# How to hook browser Print command like File->Print or File->Save

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-addons

Is there a way to HOOk browser commands in IE/FF/Chrome Like Office applications? we can hook keyboard events, but how to hook menu items??

Comment: Are you a webpage or are you a browser extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for Chrome: no. The answer for Firefox: yes. There is a [`<xul:command>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/command) in the browser window with id `cmd_print`. Attach a listener for the `command` event to it and it will be called whenever the user invokes that menu item or presses Ctrl-P. There is also a similar element with id `Browser:SavePage`.

Comment: Thanks. you have any idea about IE?

Comment: No, I know nothing about IE helper objects. It is generally not a good idea to mix questions about completely different browsers in one question - only few people know all of them.